Is there a way to train a CNN with the loss of another net?
I have 2 CNNs. One is called net and the other is called mask. Both have the same architecture but are initialised differently. My training loop looks like this:
for epoch in range(epochs):

    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}")

    net.train()
    mask.train()

    # I use the mask to prune the net
    net_masked = apply_mask(net, mask)
    
    running_loss = 0.0

    for images, labels in train_loader:
      images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)

      # I use the images to calculate the loss of the net
      outputs_net = net_masked(images)
      loss_net = criterion(outputs_net, labels)

      outputs_mask = mask(images) # I also get the loss of the mask (I don't use loss_mask.item())
      loss_mask = criterion(outputs_mask, labels)

      loss = loss_net + loss_mask*0 # Now loss looks like this : tensor(2.2969, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)

      optimizer_mask.zero_grad()

      loss.backward() # Here I try to calculate the gradients


      optimizer_mask.step()  # Update weights

      running_loss += loss_net.item()

    train_loss.append(running_loss / len(train_loader))

What I am trying to do is update the mask weighs to prune net in different ways each time. My problem is that when I try to compute the gradients I get "0" in all of them.
Why the gradients are not being computed? Maybe it's the way I am computing the loss?
